# android tablelayout text pixelated

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I'm adding cells to a table view programatically:

```
for(int i=0; i<numRows; i++){
        TableRow tr=new TableRow(mContext);
        tr.setLayoutParams(tableParams);
        for(int j=0; j<numCols; j++){
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            ImageView iv = new ImageView(mContext);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
            iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.angry_cat);

            TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
            tv.setText("some");
            tv.setTextSize(7f);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            ll.addView(iv);
            ll.addView(tv);
            tr.addView(ll);
        }
        table.addView(tr);
    }
```

But the text is coming out pixelated:
[image: cats]

How do i define the text to be smoother?

Comment: btw dont use Color.WHITE for textColor. You should do it like this: tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem locate in this place: `tv.setTextSize(7f);`
Try to change value to 14 for example and than respond what was changed.

EDIT:
And you should use 7.0f instead of 7f

EDIT1:
Try this code:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
create dimen folder like this res/values/dimensions.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="textsize">8sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: 7.0f didn't help. Of course 14 helps but I don't want the text to be bigger.

Comment: It depends of screen density, if you set text size programmaticaly  you should use mTextView.setTextSize(textSize * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density); to set text for your screen density

Comment: I'm using a  nexus 7. Tried, still doesn't help. I should be able to display text like those on icons with the same sharpness. it's much smaller than 7.

Comment: tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 7);

Comment: Also try this one way: textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
              getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
create dimen folder like this res/values/dimensions.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="textsize">8sp</dimen>
</resources>

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Color From Color xml file.
Like that:

color.xml

```
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
```

and then get color:

```
tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Comment: Doesn't help. did u notice your defining the color in XML but then taking it from android.R?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

tv.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);